# Starting a Service in a separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service

In the Android docs, it says that a Service runs in the main thread.

What happens if I start my service in a separate thread? Does it still run on the main thread?

I am not talking about using `android:process` in the manifest file, but rather something like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Start service
    }
}).start();
```

Don't worry, I will not do it like that, I am just curious.

Comment: You can't start the service inside the Thread without a Context :-)

Comment: @rIHaNJiTHiN Can't I just use my Activity if I declare my thread inside my Activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`startService()` starts a service in the main thread (the same as starting an Activity or any other component). In doesn't matter what thread you call `startService()` from.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

"When a Service component is actually created, for either of these reasons, all that the system actually does is instantiate the component and call its onCreate() and any other appropriate callbacks on the main thread."

Comment: This is my understanding too from the documentation, but does it say somewhere explicitly that it runs in the main thread no matter what? the only thing I could find is *"Note that the system calls this on your service's main thread. A service's main thread is the same thread where UI operations take place for Activities running in the same process. You should always avoid stalling the main thread's event loop. When doing long-running operations, network calls, or heavy disk I/O, you should kick off a new thread, or use AsyncTask."* Does it mean kickoff a new thread and start a Service?

Comment: It's pretty clear from the first two sentences that it's started on the main thread no matter what, if you go into debugger you can see that it's the case. It means you should kick off a new Thread within the Service, since the Service's callbacks are, by default, on the main thread. Note that IntentService does this work for you, by giving you a callback run on a new Thread in onHandleIntent().

Comment: It's the same as calling startActivity(), the new Activity is going to be on the main thread no matter where it's called from.

Comment: Ahhh, your last comment with startActivity() helped a lot. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says that a Service is not even related to multithreading by default:

> A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service
>   does not create its own thread...

You can read it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

What your code does may be very similar to calling a View's functions from a Thread other than main thread. System doesn't let you do that. Throws an exception.

Comment: There will be no exception thrown, the system will schedule a new Service to start with it's callbacks on the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking out of curiosity and don't need any code:

First you have to understand the difference between a process and a thread (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)

All the threads in your app get triggered in the app's process by default.
The Service itself is a thread so there is no reason to launch it from a separate thread (you normally launch it from the main thread, like `onCreate` method and such. It's launched by default in the same process but you can specify a separate process for it by specifying `process`name in the declaration like so: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Comment: The service itself is most definitely not a thread. "A Service is not a thread." from docs.

Comment: @svenoaks it's not but it's mostly working like an interface-less activity in a separate thread, it works in parallel

Comment: How does it work in a separate thread? It's mentioned in the doc that it runs in the UI thread.

Comment: @user2998121 You are right, I confused it with the 'IntentService', my bad